# ASP.Net MVC Exporting WebGrid to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to export a WebGrid to `PDF` and I have the following code in my controller:

```
public FileStreamResult CreatePdf()
{
    List<CertificationListViewModel> all = new List<CertificationListViewModel>();

    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        all = db.Certifications.ToList();
    }

    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: all, canPage: false, canSort: false);

    string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", "Nome"),
            grid.Column("Classification", "Classificação"),
            grid.Column("Date", "Data de Realização") 
        )
    ).ToString();
    string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table{ border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate; }</style>", gridHtml);
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
    using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        document.Open();

        var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
        xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        document.Close();
        output.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

The code is giving me a error in this line:

```
all = db.Certifications.ToList();
```

This is the error that shows up:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HIQTraining.Model.Certification>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HIQTrainingSite.ViewModel.CertificationListViewModel>'

I am not sure what the error is if someone has an ideia of what it could be I would appreciate !

P.S : I have the following `iTextSharp` libraries exported in the project:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Comment: The message is self explanatory - `all` is `List<CertificationListViewModel>` but your query is returning `List<Certification>` (not  a collection of `CertificationListViewModel`) - you need to project the query into your view model (or change the definition of `all`)

Comment: Your generic `List<CertificationListViewModel>` will only accept type `CertificationListViewModel` and your model property as a List will be of type `List<HIQTrainingSite.ViewModel.CertificationListViewModel>` so either change your `all` field type to `var` to make implicit or convert your `HIQTraining.Model.Certification` objects to `CertificationListViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your values are of different types.  (Which makes sense, I wouldn't expect "view" models to be stored in the database.)  So you'll need to in some way convert from one to the other.

For example, if your view model can be simply built with an object initializer, then you can construct it in a `.Select()` projection:

```
all = db.Certifications.ToList()
      .Select(c => new CertificationListViewModel {
          SomeProperty = c.SomeProperty,
          AnotherProperty = c.AnotherProperty
      });
```

If there are many properties, libraries like AutoMapper can help with that.

Conversely, if you actually *wanted* the list of database models, then you'd need to change the type of your variable to match that:

```
List<Certification> all = new List<Certification>();
```

Comment: I did something new:
 DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            List all = new List();
            all = db.Certifications.ToList();

And it's giving me this error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HIQTraining.Model.Certification>' to 'iTextSharp.text.List'

Comment: @PaljiloDomijilo: Yes, that's the same error.  And for the same reason.  You can't implicitly convert between entirely different types.  What type do you want your `all` variable to *be*?